# What's the difference between hyperbolic tangent and sigmoid neurons?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-neural-networks, comparison, hidden-layers

Two common activation functions used in deep learning are the hyperbolic tangent function and the sigmoid activation function. I understand that the hyperbolic tangent is just a rescaling and translation of the sigmoid function:

$\tanh(z) = 2\sigma(z) - 1$.

Is there a significant difference between these two activation functions, and in particular, **when is one preferable to the other**?

I realize that in some cases (like when estimating probabilities) outputs in the range of $[0,1]$ are more convenient than outputs that range from $[-1,1]$. I want to know if there are differences **other than convenience** which distinguish the two activation functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sigmoid > Hyperbolic tangent:**

As you mentioned, the application of Sigmoid might be more convenient than hyperbolic tangent in the cases that we need a probability value at the output (as @matthew-graves says, we can fix this with a simple mapping/calibration step). In other layers, this makes no sense.

**Hyperbolic tangent > Sigmoid:**

Hyperbolic tangent has a property called "approximates identity near the origin" which means $\tanh(0) = 0$, $\tanh'(0) = 1$, and $\tanh'(z)$ is continuous around $z=0$ (as opposed to  $\sigma(0)=0.5$ and $\sigma'(0)=0.25$). This feature (which also exists in many other activation functions such as *identity*, *arctan*, and *sinusoid*) lets the network learn efficiently even when its weights are initialized with small values. In other cases (eg *Sigmoid* and *ReLU*) these small initial values *can* be problematic.

**Further Reading:**

[Random Walk Initialization for Training Very Deep Feedforward Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6558)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it makes sense to decide activation functions based on desired properties of the output; you can easily insert a calibration step that maps the 'neural network score' to whatever units you actually want to use (dollars, probability, etc.).

So I think preference between different activation functions mostly boils down to the [different properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function#Comparison_of_activation_functions) of those activation functions (like whether or not they're continuously differentiable). Because there's just a linear transformation between the two, I think that means there isn't a meaningful difference between them.